# error django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models

I am really stuck here.  I went back and edited some models that I made a while ago and now I can't get anything to migrate without getting:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__accounts_instrument.room_id
```

The model that seems to be causing problems:

**acounts/models.py**

```py
class Instrument(models.Model):
    LEVEL = (
    ('HS', 'HS'),
    ('MS', 'MS'),
    )
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=True)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True, choices=LEVEL)
    room = models.ForeignKey(AuditionRoom, default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I've tried deleting the migration history but that throws other codes so I "undo" it.
I've tried dropping the instrument table but that didn't seem to matter.

I'm very grateful for any pointers as I am pretty frustrated at the moment.  Please let me know if you need more code snippets, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This error usually means that a field that is required was not provided, another try can be setting the `null=True, blank=True` attributes in your `room` field field.

Also you can go to the migrations folder and delete manually files that have 000*_blah-blah type of name, you can delete, probably all, but 0001_initial.py file. After that run `./manage.py makemigrations app_you_are_updateing`, it should update your database.

Comment: Thanks, @Javad.  If I add "null=True, blank=True" , delete all migrations other than 0001_initial.py, and run "manage.py makemigrations accounts" I get a huge long error that ends with "django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration students.0002_student_school dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('accounts', '0012_alter_auditionroom_event')"

Comment: If you're in development and your migrations is not very important, for other applications removed all migrations and make migrations from first for all your applications.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood that you wanted me to delete my database.  I decided to do that on my own about an hour ago actually.  I had been wanted to add and AbstractUser model so it was a good time to do it.  Things seem to be working now.  thanks for your time!