# Why does adding 'User' to my Model gives me an Internal Server Error? (Django)

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models, django-users

My Django App was working fine until I added this 'author' field to my Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):

author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=280)
```

I'm literally copying it from a article I found (from 2022), so I don't get what's wrong. This is the error the console is showing:

[image]

Here's the repository -> https://github.com/mateomaza/SocialMediaProject

Comment: It seems some problem with your migration files itself, it maybe possible that you made migrations so many times while creating model relationships.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['NOT NULL constraint failed' after adding to models.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964312/not-null-constraint-failed-after-adding-to-models-py)

Answer (score -2):

Just looking at the stack trace the author_id field is probably null somewhere.

[error django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943699/error-django-db-utils-integrityerror-not-null-constraint-failed)
https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/comments/13752/